# What is the function of 哩? (Cantonese)

Tags: cantonese

What is the function of 哩 in 哩兩個人好相似?

And how different is it if you just say 兩個人好相似?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard character for ni1 / nei1 is 呢, not [哩](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/658/), which mean 'mile'

> 呢兩個人好相似

**呢** in this context functions as '**this**'

呢 (this)

兩個人 (two persons)

好相似 (very alike)

> **呢** http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1029/
>
> jyutping: ni1 / nei1
>
> [粵][pron][adj] **this**

~

> *And how different is it if you just say 兩個人好相似?*

- 呢兩個人好相似 (this two people are very alike)
- 兩個人好相似 (two people are very alike)

It is just like omitting 'this' in "(this) two people are very alike" in English.

*You can omit '呢/this' if we know which two persons the sentence is referring to*

Comment: Thanks. I was reading lecture notes from a cantonese site and this came as the transcription. I am familiar with the standard usage for “this”. Thanks again